# Did McDonald's bankroll The Founder?

Tags: production, the-founder

I'm wondering what level of involvement McDonald's had in this film. I reckon if developers of the film were looking for investors, McDonald's would have been able to pay for the whole project in a second.

Answer (score 4):

**No, they didn't.**

According to IMDB, Wikipedia and other industry sources, the funding for "The Founder" came from two sources; Don Hanfield (through his company [The Combine](http://www.jeremyleerenner.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=828&sid=72a15d03606d9abc4c318a008d9b3bdb)) and matched funding from FilmNation Entertainment, using money from [Roadshow Films](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/roadshow-films-invests-filmnation-758697).

None of these funding sources seem to be owned by or affiliated to McDonalds, nor does there appear to have been any direct involvement between McDonalds and the filmmakers in terms of assistance with filming, archive footage or locations, which the makers had to [build from scratch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4276820/trivia?item=tr2772295).

---

In a [Q&A with a rep from FilmNation](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/berlin-filmnation-svp-says-michael-771065), she explictly stated that McDonalds, though unwilling to help, were at least willing to not hinder

> **Q.** *THR [The Hollywood Reporter] has reported that McDonald’s won’t try to block the biopic,
>   even though it doesn’t paint the most flattering picture of Ray
>   Kroc.*
>
> ***Tara Erer:*** Several buyers have already told me that helps. No one wants a legal battle.